# How to specify startup priorities in Kubernetes on Azure?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a Kubernetes cluster running on Azure, it has two Deployment pods a database and a Tomcat application server. Problem is that when I start the cluster, sometimes the application starts before Tomcat, and in the application startup I have a function that accesses the database, and the function fails because it cannot connect.

Ideally, I would define a dependency that the Tomcat application server starts after the database pod finishes starting. Is there a way to specify priorities in Azure Kubernetes deployments yaml?

Comment: Kubernetes doesn't have that concept.  What should happen if the database fails while the application is running?  That's not really a different case from the database being unavailable at startup time, but a "depends-on" relationship can't handle that.  It's a common enough approach to let the application container crash and restart until the database is ready.

Comment: In other words, the application has the responsibility of handling this.